# Property access of yielded objects

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, yield

I am trying to access the property of an object passed back using yield.

```
function*test() {
 console.log(yield)
 console.log(yield(true).test)
}

var generator = test()

generator.next({ test: true })
generator.next({ test: true })
generator.next({ test: true })
```

However, the property is not accessed.

```
Object { test: true }
Object { test: true }
```

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this just the way it works and I should just assign the yield result to a temporary variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misreading your parens. `yield` is a keyword, not a function.

```
console.log(yield(true).test)
```

is the same as

```
console.log(yield (true).test);
```

or

```
console.log(yield (true.test));
```

so you are still logging the result of the `yield`, the `.test` is not processing the value passed into `.next`.

You want

```
console.log((yield true).test);
```